# How do I show others what I am capable of?

Tags: application, career-path

I just turned sixteen this January, and I have started thinking about where I will go to pursue research in theoretical physics and mathematics. I live in India, and, sadly speaking, research here in India is awful, even though many claims of scientific advancements in India are made. First, I would like to share what I do at home.

I have mastered differential and integral calculus, and I have independently proved, and discovered some of my own proofs of theorems in Real Analysis(Proofs which I haven't seen in some other source, but they might exist). I have also independently discovered the well known techniques of solutions to certain kinds of differential equations, without having any knowledge of how to solve them. I continue to explore higher level mathematics, and try my best to prove each theorem I encounter myself.

Now, the thing is, nobody at school, neither the teachers nor my friends, know anything about this. Even my parents are not fully aware about all this, but I try my best to share this with them. At school, the curriculum is such that the teachers are teaching to the test, and a heavy focus on contests and olympiads is laid, and to choose subjects of your own choice, you have to score high enough in subjects like Social Science and English, which don't even matter in research. Unnecessary debates and discussions are held, and I try my best to not share anything with these guys, to prevent getting into an hour long debate on what you should pursue.

In India, the major institutions are the Indian Institutes of Technology, Indian Institute of Science etc, where almost everybody focuses on getting into the IIT. To get an admission in the IIT, a standardised test, comprising of problems from Math, Physics, Chemistry and MAT has to be given. The admissions are solely decided by the score obtained in this test, which comprises of contest-like questions, which do not describe the research capability of the candidate. Even coaching centres have been set up all over the country, which train for this exam(called the JEE exam). The situation is really worse, and recently, I was demotivated by my teacher for not scoring enough in my social science exam. I have gotten used to this.

I would like to get admitted to institutions like MIT, Harvard, and I have read how I apply for them and what are the requirements for admission. The main thing is I have to distinguish myself from others, take part in extra-curricular activities etc, and maybe win math/science contests. But the thing is, I am not great at contests, which are timed, and I rarely would like to participate at school, where conditions are horrible. I have started taking leaves from school, because I think nothing productive is going on there.

Now, I would like to ask if I apply for these institutes, how do I share what I am capable of? As a young mathematician, I think I am really doing well, and will do well in research too. But, other than my notebook, where I write all my thoughts and all my findings, I don't have anything that can show my abilities. If I just tell my abilities to them, like I did here, they would not believe in me, which I understand.

So, my question is, how do I show the institutes my abilities? Is it necessary for me to win contests at national/international levels, which is not that easy?

Comment: You might want to consider less than stellar U.S. universities as well. There are probably over 30 U.S. universities at which you would not come close to reaching the upper limit of what they could offer you (courses including graduate level courses, classmates who will eventually get a Ph.D. in math or physics, faculty to work with, etc.), and if you really excel then you could attend graduate school at MIT, Harvard, etc., which would be more important for your future in mathematics or physics than what university you attended as an undergraduate.

Comment: You can try and get into the national team for the International Physics/Mathematics/Informatics Olympiad. A medal there can certainly get you far.

Comment: Could you demonstrate your talent by solving some important, open problem in physics or proving some important conjecture in math?

Comment: Take a look at these stories. Maybe there is one that could apply to you: http://www.gradschoolhub.com/10-youngest-people-ever-to-achieve-a-doctorate-degree/

Comment: @Justas Let's be realistic: He/She 's 16. Reading about open problems, if one can do it, is great. Expecting to solve one right away (or even before starting univeraity) is not. The sole case (in mathematics) that I have heard of is regarding an improvment of the bounds in the Bertrand's postulate. And even in that case, I am quite positive that there was guidence by a senior. @ OP As a side note, you can consider Grothendieck's story: Graduated from a far from bigname university (and even failed a year) only to revolutionize algebraic geometry later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not truly a genius there is no way around standard procedures. But if you are:

1. Make a paper
2. Publish it in a journal
3. Get citations and acknowledgements if the work is good

That is how science works.

You can contact a professor closest to you for help. Show some raw paper made by you, and if you truly are capable then he will gladly help. The professor has a realistic set of journals in mind that might be willing to publish your paper. If you have published in some of the top journals, then you have earned a special way around standard procedures.

You do not need any highly branded college diplomas, recognition is all about skill. If you are capable to publish in a top journal without diploma, then I think that you have already accomplished your goal.

Comment: This answer is really appreciable. I always think about my work being my recognition, but, you know, psychologically I sometimes feel scared, and even when I am so confident about myself, I ask:"Will I be able to do it?What if not?". I know this is a stupid thought, which I should just throw in the trash, but when you constantly get demotivated by people around you, this thought may come. Anyways, I am really pumped up by your answer, +1.

Comment: @Siddhant JeffE is right, I cannot overemphasize that point. What you are asking for is special treatment beyond standard procedures for special treatment like getting in by success in competition. The only way is to show significant result. You should not expect any empathy from anyone, because you are trying to be on top of the top and not getting to top is already a non-empathy waking thing. As a person that got in with the success in competition I can tell that for many hearing about that was already kind of wow experience. This is a step beyond.

Comment: Many PhDs in math don't publish almost anything before graduation. It is unlikely that he has found something truly new, he just says that he has the potential and the ambition to study combined with talent.

Answer (score 5):

To apply for admission as an undergraduate at ... (MIT, Harvard, etc.) ... their web sites shows the steps you need.  There is an exam (SAT, Scholastic Aptitude Test) such applicants may take.  Probably there are opportunities to take it in your country as well, but maybe just in one or two cities, so you may have to travel there to do it.  (16-year-olds generally haven't published papers.)